# Usage of setInterval method and asking for jQuery alternate

Tags: javascript, jquery

`window.setInterval("moveUp(fire,2)","100");`

in the code above fire is a object represting a div. I want to pass this object to moveUp method and call this method continuosly.

My problem is window.setInterval does not accepts fire object like this and gives error as fire is not defined. Although i am using fire object at other places as well. Besides this i also want to know if i can do the same using jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass a string to `setInterval` then it will be `eval`ed in the global scope. Don't do that. Pass a function instead, and keep the existing scope.

```
var fire = something;
var func = function () { 
    moveUp(fire, 2); 
};
setInterval(func,100);
```

> Besides this i also want to know if i can do the same using jQuery.

jQuery is just a JavaScript library. It isn't a different language. It doesn't have alternatives for basic JavaScript.

Comment: I was actually looking for a jQuery alternative that has some animation behaviour

Comment: What i am actually willing to achieve with this is a animation and i was actually looking for some jQuery help on a animation library.Yes i understand jQuery is a extension to javascript.

Comment: @sushil bharwani i presume you are aware of http://api.jquery.com/animate/ so whats it NOT doing for you?

Answer (score 1):

Best Way would be to use an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function(){
  moveUp(fire,2); 
},100);
```

It actually does look a little bit like jQuery now... kidding aside, there is no `setInterval` Implementation for jQuery since its syntax and the cross browser capabilities are just fine the way they are - are they not?