# Re-using a variable inside jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function. This function is called with a setTimeout upon a form submit.

```
function get_progress( fileID, filename) {
$.ajax({
    url: filename,
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'read_file.php',
            data: 'filename=' +filename,
            success: function(html) {
                document.getElementById(fileID).innerHTML = html + ' <img src="images/loading.gif" />'
                setInterval("get_progress(fileID,filename)",400);
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

I am running into errors as soon as the setInterval is triggered upon success. It appears that fileID and filename are ***empty variables***, despite having values in them before the code reaches the success state.

Why is this happening ? Do I have to assign them as global variables instead ?

Comment: Quick (somewhat-unrelated) question: why not use jQuery for your success function too?  e.g. `$('#'+fileID).append('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of setInterval method and asking for jQuery alternate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562399/usage-of-setinterval-method-and-asking-for-jquery-alternate)

Comment: @David Dorward: how can this be a duplicate ? My problem is accessing a variable within an ajax function, while that link you pasted has got to do with setinterval

Comment: @NickAldwin: yeah I figured someone will ask this. I wrote this up right before leaving for the holidays. My mind was already on vacation mode :P

Comment: — it is the same problem - using variables in a given scope with setTimeout or setInterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working because `setInterval` with a string evaluates the code in the global scope.  You need to do this with an anonymous function instead, which creates a closure:

```
setInterval(function() {
    get_progress(fileID,filename);
} ,400);
```

From the [MDN documentation for `window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

> This syntax [a string of code] is not recommended for the same reasons that make using eval() a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
success: function(html) {
    $('#' + fileid).append('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
    setInterval(function() {
        get_progress(fileID,filename);
    }, 400);
}
```